# How to get the principal after a successful SSL handshake using Mina?

Tags: java, authentication, ssl, apache-mina, principal

I am using Mina with a SslFilter, configured with "client authentication needed".

Once a connection is made and a handshake is done, how to get the certificate (or the principal) of the peer on the other side of the connection from my subclass of the IoHandler on the server ?

**Edit:** in other words, how to get the relation between a IoSession and the principal once the handshake is done and the IoHandler.sessionOpened() is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can get the `SSLSession` using [`SslFilter.getSslSession(...)`](http://mina.apache.org/report/trunk/apidocs/org/apache/mina/filter/ssl/SslFilter.html#getSslSession%28org.apache.mina.core.session.IoSession%29). Then, use [`SSLSession.getPeerCertificateChain()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSession.html#getPeerCertificateChain%28%29) to get the client certificate chain. The actual client certificate is at position 0 in that array.

Comment: It looks like the solution. Let me try it first, then I will accept it. Thank you.

Comment: SslFilter.getSslSession(), when called from IoHandler.sessionOpened(), returns null. Probably this method is called immediatly after a socket connection is estalished. I don't know how to get notified after the end of the handshake. Could you help me please?

Comment: I'm not sure. Don't feel you need to accept the answer if it doesn't actually answer the question completely. As a guess by looking at the javadoc, I'd try to set the `USE_NOTIFICATION` attribute and look for `SESSION_SECURED` message.

Comment: It works, but this is a trick which is not really well documented. Also, I need to add two "if" in my subclass of IoHandler.messageReceived() to differentiate the events from the messages really sent by the remote peer - not really CPU efficient. I wonder if there is a better way to design the event listener.

Answer (score 0):

You don't work with the IoHandler directly for that, it is done using the [SSLContext](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLContext.html) which you need to provide for the [SslFilter](http://mina.apache.org/report/trunk/apidocs/org/apache/mina/filter/ssl/SslFilter.html) constructor. If you take a look at the [echo server](http://mina.apache.org/report/trunk/xref/org/apache/mina/example/echoserver/) example, you can see that the actual check is done in DefaultTrustManagerFactory. Personally I find that example a little too complicated, if I can find something simpler I will post it.

Comment: I already wrote my own TrustManagerFactory which I set in the SSLContext, which I provide to the SslFilter via its constructor. My TrustManager is getting called when someone connects, this part is fine. What I need to know is how to get the relation between a IoSession and the other peer's certificate (or principal) once the handshake is done.